# Build FFMPEG 4.2 with Android NDK r20

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am trying to build FFMPEG 4.2 using Android NDK r20 and I am having an issue with `configure`.

I followed Ilia Kosynkin's blog post (https://medium.com/@ilja.kosynkin/building-ffmpeg-4-0-for-android-with-clang-642e4911c31e) and with a few minor changes to `build.sh` I successfully built FFMPEG 4.0.2 using Android NDK r17c for API level 14 on an Ubuntu 16 VM.

I updated FFMPEG to 4.2 and the Android NDK to r20 and got these and other compiler errors.

```
~/android-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:61:7: error: expected identifier or '('
char* getenv(const char* __name);
      ^
./config.h:17:19: note: expanded from macro 'getenv'
#define getenv(x) NULL
                  ^
~/android-ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/8.0.7/include/stddef.h:105:18: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
```

and many like this:

```
./libavutil/libm.h:54:32: error: static declaration of 'cbrt' follows non-static declaration
static av_always_inline double cbrt(double x)
                               ^
~/android-ndk/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:191:8: note: previous declaration is here
double cbrt(double __x);
       ^
```

In addition to `cbrt` there were about a dozen or so other math related functions redefined (e.g. lrint, round, trunc, inet_aton). I opened the generated `config.h`, commented out `#define getenv(x) NULL` and changed a bunch of defines like `#define HAVE_CBRT 0` to `#define HAVE_CBRT 1`. I ran `make` and `make install` and the build was successful.

So my question is, are there ffmpeg options that I can pass to `configure` that will generate a config.h that I don't have to modify in order to get a successful build?

EDIT: Additional information from config.log.

It appears that `check_mathfunc` in `configure` is failing for NDK r20 but I can't tell why. Here is an example of a link command failing for the check for `truncf`. The error does not make any sense to me.

```
~/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
    -L~/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x
    -L~/android-ndk/platforms/android-29/arch-arm/usr/lib
    --fix-cortex-a8 -lc --sysroot=~/android-ndk/sysroot -fPIE -pie
    -o /tmp/ffconf.1OTX8pa8/test /tmp/ffconf.1OTX8pa8/test.o -lgcc

~/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld:
    fatal error: -f/--auxiliary may not be used without -shared
```

EDIT 2: The error seems to be caused by the **-pie** option (Create a position independent executable). Previous version of FFMPEG did not have these 2 lines in the **configure** script for android:

```
add_cflags -fPIE
add_ldexeflags -fPIE, -pie
```

If I add **-shared** to `add_ldexeflags` I get the error "*-shared and -pie are incompatible*". If I replace **-pie** with **-shared**, `check_mathfunc` succeeds but I don't know if that is the correct thing to do. It seems odd that **-fPIE** requires **-shared** but **-pie** cannot be used with it.

Replacing **-pie** with **-shared** seems to fix the `config.h` file but now I get `'sys/sysctl.h' file not found` during the build of `libavutil`. NDK r20 has 2 instances of `sysctl.h` and NDK r17c has 1 but none of them are in a directory named `sys`.

EDIT 3: I am going to chalk this one up to a bug in the FFMPEG `configure` script. `configure` checks for the existence of a function by generating a small source file that uses the function and then compiling and linking the generated file. If anything fails the function is not available. For NDK r17c, `check_func sysctl` fails and the build excludes `sysctl` functionality. For some reason, the test succeeds for NDK r20 because `check_func` does not verify whether or not `sys/sysctl.h` exists it just prototypes `sysctl()` and calls it. I solved this issue by adding a function to `configure` named `check_sysfunc` that tries to include `sys/sysctl.h`. I now get past this error and have a new one about an implicit declaration being invalid. I have to assume it is also a deficiency in `configure` and hopefully there won't be too many more of these.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to do the same thing as you. Apparently, this guy (not me) manage to compile ffmpeg4.2 with NDK r20. So far it seem to work with `ARCH=armv7a`

[Youtube] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP8SEAhcq5M
[Github] https://github.com/binglingziyu/ffmpeg-android-build

[P.s. I don't have enough reputation to post as a comment... so yeah...]

Answer (score 1):

Passing `-fPIE` to ld directly is wrong. That's a compiler flag. The linker flag is spelled `-pie`. `-fPIE` is `-f PIE`, which is a completely different argument:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

> -f name
>   --auxiliary=name When creating an ELF shared object, set the internal DT_AUXILIARY field to the specified name. This tells the dynamic
>   linker that the symbol table of the shared object should be used as an
>   auxiliary filter on the symbol table of the shared object name. If you
>   later link a program against this filter object, then, when you run
>   the program, the dynamic linker will see the DT_AUXILIARY field. If
>   the dynamic linker resolves any symbols from the filter object, it
>   will first check whether there is a definition in the shared object
>   name. If there is one, it will be used instead of the definition in
>   the filter object. The shared object name need not exist. Thus the
>   shared object name may be used to provide an alternative
>   implementation of certain functions, perhaps for debugging or for
>   machine specific performance.
>
> This option may be specified more than once. The DT_AUXILIARY entries
>   will be created in the order in which they appear on the command line.

As for the other issue:

> NDK r20 has 2 instances of sysctl.h and NDK r17c has 1 but none of them are in a directory named sys.

I just filed https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/1068, but I'm not sure if we'll fix that one. Apparently its use is strongly discouraged. Fixing the source to not use that is probably the better call.